# alfresco files thumbnail view not appearing

Tags: solr, alfresco, alfresco-share, solr4, alfresco-webscripts

Hi I am new to alfresco and trying to fix a prod issue, all of a sudden files(mostly jpeg/png) uploaded earlier(before 1 months) cannot be viewed under folder and it is showing as empty folder. but when i click on download it is downloading the full set of files.

The alfresco version is 5.2 and solr is solr4.

I went through the logs and found errors like

**Alfresco Log:**

020-08-22 11:41:03,468 ERROR [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime] [http-apr-9090-exec-38] Exception from executeScript: 072223632 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 072224529 Failed to execute script '/abc/Get Images/get-images.get.js (in repository store workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts Extensions)': 072224528 Failed to execute search: PATH:"/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:abc/cm:documentLibrary/cm:Images//*" AND TYPE:"abc:abcImage"
org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException: 072223632 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 072224529 Failed to execute script '/abc/Get Images/get-images.get.js (in repository store workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts Extensions)': 072224528 Failed to execute search: PATH:"/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:abc/cm:documentLibrary/cm:Images//*" AND TYPE:"cvp:cvpImage"

SOLR logs:

Namespace prefix ab is not mapped to a namespace URI

I have tried rebuilding indexes in solr4 too but no luck.

Kindly check and help out in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you re-built the indexes did you also clear out the alfrescoModels directory? It sounds like your SOLR server doesn't know about your custom type. Sometimes you have to clear out that directory to force it to fetch the latest model.